# Is “drop the pomp for the profound” a cliché or the Time writer’s own wording?

Tags: phrases

In connection with my question on the Royal Wedding I posted today, I’m interested in the phrase, “*drop the pomp for the profound*” in the following line appearing in the Time article (April 29) titled “Traveling Man: Brian Williams Explains Why He Ditched the Royal Wedding”

> “NBC anchor Brian Williams chose to abandon his plan to cover Will and Kate's wedding — just hours after touching down in London — and return to the U.S. to cover the devastation caused by tornadoes, floods and storms. ---Which we can't help but admire. Let's face it, the Royal Wedding is going to be covered no matter what, but it's nice to know that one of our favorite journalists is still willing to “*drop the pomp for the profound*.”

I was hooked to the phrase, “drop the pomp for the profound.” because it sounds classic and cool to my ears (YMMV). Is this an established phrase, or just the author’s invention?

Comment: FYI (for your information), _hooked to the phrase_ is not really idiomatic English.   A much better substitute would be _drawn_, e.g., _I was drawn to the phrase_.

Comment: @Bilare. Thanks for your advice. I  intended to say 'interested in.' and found the use of 'be hooked' totally wrong by checking dictionary after being pointed out by you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a cliche. It's just a rhyming phrase expressing that someone (Brian Williams), who was on the verge of doing the wedding, got some sense at the last moment. He left the royal couple at the altar, and maybe the world is a little bit better place for that.

Comment: Aye, the less journalists here the better.

Comment: @Orbling: This is an English site, so am I allowed to say that "less" should be "fewer" in your comment? :)

Comment: +1 Seems reasonable enough that it isn't a cliché based on the Google search results; in fact, this page is the first hit for "drop the pomp for the profound"!

Comment: @user7834: Yes, the less mistakes I make per sentence the better. ;-)